# Can humans shorten their sleeping patterns?

Tags: human-biology, human-genetics, sleep

Can sleeping patterns be trained, or are they genetic? I read that a human needs to sleep at least 4 hours. Can sleeping time be reduced without having a negative impact?

Comment: not really an answer, but this article about the myth of the 8-hour sleep was quite interesting! http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-16964783

Comment: a related question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/is-it-possible-to-live-without-health-problems-sleeping-one-day-and-not-the-othe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Polyphasic sleep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphasic_sleep) can allow people to sleep at multiple regular intervals throughout the day and allows people to get by with less total sleep. I don't know of any training that can help people reduce the amount of monophasic sleep they need without a negative impact.